# What type of bowl is best for a fruit salad?

Tags: storage-method

I am planning on making a fruit salad for coworkers and want to make sure that none of the fruit start to go bad because of the contact with the bowl.

I am planning on using apples, oranges, grapes, pine apple, and possibly bananas.

What would be the best type of bowl to transport and serve this in: metal, glass, plastic, etc?

Comment: The absolute best bowl would be a watermelon cut in a basket shape, right? ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the bowl has anything to do with it, unless it is some sort of reactive metal, but you don't normally find food grade bowls made of a reactive metal?

To stop surface oxidation of non-acidic fruit (apples, bananas etc.) coat them with a suitable weak acid. See this previous answer  [How to Prevent Apples from turning Brown](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9018/how-to-prevent-apples-from-turning-brown/9020#9020)

Answer (score 1):

A clear glass bowl of course.  There are many materials available which would serve the purpose just fine, aluminum is a material I would advise against though.

You are making a beautiful, colorful, fragrant fruit salad - show it off in a nice clear glass bowl.  All other things being fairly equal, go for the flavor/art/hunger/munch appeal, and serve it proudly.

Answer (score 0):

If it's on display for any length of time it might be helpful to choose a bowl which allows air circulation to prevent detoriation (eg. a mesh type) or to be careful to arrange fruit so that they allow this.