# alternative of vinegar for preventing fruits from turning black?

Tags: substitutions, fruit

We use vinegar to prevent fruit from turning black.When we don't have vinegar what alternative is used to prevent fruits from turning black.

Comment: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9018/how-to-prevent-apples-from-turning-brown?rq=1

Comment: I see this as a full duplicate. The OP excludes one of many possible methods against browning, but the answers there list many possible methods beside vinegar.